# APEX html link with Variable

Tags: html, oracle, hyperlink, apex

hello I want to display a link in Apex with html, but there is still something to be added to the link, as it should differ from email to email. I tried to append this with a variable that I take from a database, but I can't get the right structure of the link. I hope someone can help me. :)

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sk5eL.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you looking for APEX_PAGE.GET_URL function? https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/GET_URL-Function.htm#AEAPI30190